# Disable check boxes upon retrieval of radio button value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two radio buttons on my web page and bunch of check boxes underneath them. below is the code:

```html
 <input type="radio" id="RadInterest0" value="Interested" required data-val="true" data-val-required="The Interested field is required." name="Reassignment.ReassignmentInterested">Interested                           
 <input type="radio" id="RadInterest1" value="Not Interested" required checked="checked" name="Reassignment.ReassignmentInterested">Not Interested                           

    <div class="form-group row" id="reassignChecks">
                <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="1" id="chkLoc0" /> 1                
                <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="2" id="chkLoc1" /> 2                
                <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="3" id="chkLoc2" /> 3               
               <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="4" id="chkLoc3" /> 4                
               <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="5" id="chkLoc4" /> 5               
               <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="6" id="chkLoc5" /> 6                
              <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="7" id="chkLoc6" /> 7               
             <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="8" id="chkLoc7" /> 8               
             <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="9" id="chkLoc8" /> 9               
            <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="10" id="chkLoc9" /> 10    
</div>
```

These bunch of checkboxes are generated by for loop. I am just showing the rendered HTML on the web page.

On the click of "Interested" radio button, I want to enable all the checkboxes  and on the click of "Not Interested" check box, I want to disable and uncheck all check boxes. This is working fine with below code:

```
 <script>
        $('#RadInterest1').on('change', function () {
            const isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

            $('#reassignChecks').addClass('disableSection', isChecked);
           
            $('#reassignChecks input[type="checkbox"]')
                .attr('disabled', isChecked)
                .prop('checked', false)
                ;

        
        });
  
     </script>  

     $('#RadInterest0').on('change', function () {
            const isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

            $('#reassignChecks').removeClass('disableSection', isChecked);
       
            $('#reassignChecks input[type="checkbox"]')
                .removeAttr('disabled', isChecked)
                .prop('checked', false)
                ;

           
        });
```

The issue is when I retrieve the value of the radio button from database and if "Not Interested" is already clicked on load of the page then the check boxes underneath the radio button are already enabled. I don't want to enable them if the "Not Interested" radio button is clicked or if "Not Interested" radio button is already clicked on the retrieval of the radio button Value from the database. Below is the screen shot:

[image]

If the "Interested" radio button is already clicked on the retrieval of the value from the database then I want to keep the radio buttons that were already checked and all the checkboxes enabled.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On document ready you can use the following code to check and disabled the check boxes:

```
if($('#RadInterest1').is(':checked')){
  $('#reassignChecks input[type="checkbox"]')
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    .prop('checked', false)
    ;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
//check here
if($('#RadInterest1').is(':checked')){
  $('#reassignChecks input[type="checkbox"]')
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    .prop('checked', false)
    ;
}

$('#RadInterest1').on('change', function () {
    const isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#reassignChecks').addClass('disableSection', isChecked);
    $('#reassignChecks input[type="checkbox"]')
        .attr('disabled', isChecked)
        .prop('checked', false)
        ;        
});

$('#RadInterest0').on('change', function () {
    const isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#reassignChecks').removeClass('disableSection', isChecked);
    $('#reassignChecks input[type="checkbox"]')
        .removeAttr('disabled', isChecked)
        .prop('checked', false)
        ;          
});

function AnyLocation(){ }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="RadInterest0" value="Interested" required data-val="true" data-val-required="The Interested field is required." name="Reassignment.ReassignmentInterested">Interested                           
 <input type="radio" id="RadInterest1" value="Not Interested" required checked="checked" name="Reassignment.ReassignmentInterested">Not Interested                           

<div class="form-group row" id="reassignChecks">
<input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="1" id="chkLoc0" /> 1                
  <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="2" id="chkLoc1" /> 2                
  <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="3" id="chkLoc2" /> 3               
  <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="4" id="chkLoc3" /> 4                
  <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="5" id="chkLoc4" /> 5               
  <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="6" id="chkLoc5" /> 6                
  <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="7" id="chkLoc6" /> 7               
  <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="8" id="chkLoc7" /> 8               
  <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="9" id="chkLoc8" /> 9               
  <input onclick="AnyLocation()" name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="10" id="chkLoc9" /> 10    
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @Mamun, Is their any way to combine all three code together in jquery. Both OnChange and checked code that you referred above

Comment: @rimi, no, you cannot as the operations are happening on two different state (one is in onChange of the check box and the other is on the pageLoad).